# Rmagick error while running Rails 3.2 application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rmagick

I am working on an old project which is having Ruby version 1.9.3p and Rails 3.2.13

This is my Gemfile:

```
gem 'rails', '3.2.13'
gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.4.1', :group => [:production, :staging]
gem "paperclip", "~> 2.3"
gem "rmagick", "~> 2.13.1", :require => 'RMagick'
```

When I run bundle install, I am getting an error as:

> An error occurred while installing rmagick (2.13.2), and Bundler
>   cannot continue. Make sure that `gem install rmagick -v '2.13.2'`
>   succeeds before bundling.

When I run the above command, I am getting error as:

> abcuser@myvm:~/Desktop/report_master$ gem install rmagick -v '2.13.2'
>   Building native extensions.  This could take a while... ERROR:  Error
>   installing rmagick:   ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
>
> ```
> current directory: /home/abcuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@proj/gems/rmagick-2.13.2/ext/RMagick
> ```
>
> /home/abcuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551/bin/ruby -r
>   ./siteconf20160603-8257-drbei5.rb extconf.rb checking for Ruby version
>
> > = 1.8.5... yes checking for gcc... yes checking for Magick-config... no Can't install RMagick 2.13.2. Can't find Magick-config in
> >     /home/abcuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@proj/bin:/home/abcuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@global/bin:/home/abcuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551/bin:/home/abcuser/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
>
> *** extconf.rb failed *** Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check
>   the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may need configuration
>   options.
>
> Provided configuration options:   --with-opt-dir  --without-opt-dir
>     --with-opt-include  --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
>     --with-opt-lib  --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib    --with-make-prog
>     --without-make-prog     --srcdir=.  --curdir
>     --ruby=/home/abcuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551/bin/ruby
>
> To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log
>   which can be found here:
>
> /home/abcuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@proj/extensions/x86-linux/1.9.1/rmagick-2.13.2/mkmf.log
>
> extconf failed, exit code 1
>
> Gem files will remain installed in
>   /home/abcuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@proj/gems/rmagick-2.13.2 for
>   inspection. Results logged to
>   /home/abcuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@proj/extensions/x86-linux/1.9.1/rmagick-2.13.2/gem_make.out

Please help me out of this error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ERROR: Error installing rmagick: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

This could be because you don't have `node.js` installed :

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

Or because , simply,  you don't have RMagick installed:

```
sudo apt-get install imagemagick libmagickwand-dev
```

Answer (score 3):

Just a little suggestion: 
pay attention to ImageMagick Security Issue.
[know more](https://imagetragick.com/)

Comment: Nice suggestion indeed.